# Integral formula containing cumulative distribution function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mu$ prob measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and F the associated cumulative distribution function.

I found the formula $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x)(1-F(x)) dx \, =
\, \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x-y|d\mu(x)d\mu(y) $
in a paper that I am studying but I cannot prove it.

Does anyone know how to do it ? Any hint/idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(t) (1-F(t)) \, dt
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{x \le t} \, d\mu(x)
\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{y > t} \, d\mu(y)
\, dt
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}}
1_{x \le t < y} \, dt \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)
\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (y-x) 1_{y \ge x} \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)
\end{align}